# Preposition for singing and guitar

Tags: prepositions

If someone is playing songs on the guitar and people are singing songs related to that playing, how do you say it most naturally?

1. We are singing songs to the guitar?
2. We are singing songs under the guitar?
3. We are singing songs with the guitar?
4. We are singing songs while someone plays the guitar?

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable set of phrases is:

1. We are singing songs to the guitar.
2. We are singing songs accompanied by the guitar.
3. We are singing songs along with the guitar.

Comment: Agreed (though I had to check on 'singing songs to the guitar') (and look up 'songs to the piano'!) But on ELU, linked and attributed references are required to support claims (which otherwise can come across as, and sometimes sadly are, mere opinion).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _The Owl looked up to the stars above, And sang to a small guitar..._ (Edward Lear)

Comment: @Kate Bunting Bong-trees. I'd forgotten that one.